# AngularJS access objects properties after fetching it from a service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, callback

I have a local configuration file I'm using for my AngularJS app. It's stored as local JSON file and am using a service to fetch its' content. Once I load the file the file, I'm storing it in an object. Now I have a range slider who's values are also stored in this config file. But I'm unable to access the objects' properties outside of the callback. Logging the object comes up as undefined if I log it outside the callback. Initially I had used an angular expression as an attribute in the slider element but that throws an Angular parsing error. How can I access the config properties outside of the functions that calls it from the service?

```
<div class="col-md-11">
     <rzslider rz-slider-model="ageSlider.minValue"
               rz-slider-high="ageSlider.maxValue"
               rz-slider-options="ageSlider.options">
      </rzslider>
 </div>
```

HTML

```
  function getConfigData() {

    return Service.getConfigData().then(function(data){

        $scope.config = data;
        console.log("Config Data retrieved", $scope.config);

    })

}
getConfigData();

$scope.ageSlider = {
        minValue: 0,
        maxValue: 90,
        options: {
            floor: 0,
            ceil: 100,
            step: 1
        }
    };
```

JS: I would like to use the config objects' properties to set the min and max of the slider.

```
    function getConfigData() {
        return $http.get('/static/json/config.json')
            .then(getConfigDataSuccess);

        function getConfigDataSuccess(response) {
            var config = response.data;

            return config;
        }
    }
```

Service

Comment: At which point are you setting ageslider with your config values?

Comment: That's the issue...I'm unable to use the "config" object's properties as the min or max. For example, I had replaced the minValue or "10" to config.options[0].min but that comes up as undefined.

Comment: If I reference $scope.config anywhere outside of that function, it's undefined

Comment: The API call is asynchronous, and the setting for $scope.ageSlider is synchronous. $scope.ageSlider needs to be set AFTER the API call is completed (in your `then(...)` method). Right now, $scope.ageSlider is set before the API call is completed, so the value is always the state before your config file is downloaded, which is always `undefined` at that point.

Comment: Would using a $setTimout be a good idea? Any code that needs reference to the config object would get delayed until the call is finished?

Comment: No, because you can't be sure how long the API call will take to resolve. You should setup binding code inside your `then(...)` success statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
updateAgeSlider({});
getConfigData();

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function getConfigData () {
  ConfigService.get().then(updateAgeSlider);
}

function updateAgeSlider (config) {
  $scope.ageSlider = {
    minValue: config.options[0].min || 0,
    maxValue: config.options[0].max || 90,
    options: {
      floor: 0,
      ceil: 100,
      step: 1
    }
  };
}
```

And service:

```
function get () {
  return $http.get('/static/json/config.json').then(success);

  function success (response) {
    return response.data;
  }
}
```

**[Edit] Multiple sliders:**

```
updateSliders();
getConfigData();

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function getConfigData () {
  ConfigService.get().then(updateSliders);
}

function updateSliders (configSliders) {
  configSliders = configSliders || {};
  var allSliders = ['ageSlider'];

  for (var key in myExpectedSliders) {
    var sliderName = allSliders[key];
    $scope[sliderName] = getSliderConfig(configSliders[sliderName]);
  }
}

function getSliderConfig (configSlider) {
  configSlider = configSlider || {};
  return {
    minValue: configSlider.min || 0,
    maxValue: configSlider.max || 90,
    options: {
      floor: 0,
      ceil: 100,
      step: 1
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: freakin' awesome! Thank you

Comment: And let's say I have multiple slider values for different sliders in my config file, I can just add them as required in the function called after the .then?

Comment: @AnishS., you can but that's dirty. Your server response should be using named properties. So instead of `config.options[0].min` it should have given you `config.ageSlider.min`. Then you can simply bind `$scope.sliders = data`. And in your view, you could use `sliders.ageSlider.minValue`.